# What SP2010 features don't work for a Visitor using IE6

Tags: ie6, internet-explorer, intranet, content-rating, tagging

OK - So there's a lot of talk about IE6 not being supported, that IE6 wasn't tested, and IE6 performs really badly for a Web Publisher / Contributor - **but what features don't work for the end-user?** Will a Visitor be able to add a comment to a blog, rate a page, tag a page, manage their tags...?

Answer (score 2):

I saw two good posts about this earlier in the year:

- [What SharePoint 2010 looks like with Internet Explorer 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/maximeb/what-sharepoint-2010-looks-like-with-internet-explorer-6)
- [What can work with Internet Explorer 6 and SharePoint 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/maximeb/what-can-work-with-internet-explorer-6-and-sharepoint-2010)

Tags will work, but there is so much other stufff that doesn't that it makes the whole experience unpleasant.  I would definitely not recommend using SP2010 with IE6.

Comment: Thanks Rob:) these two blogs have given me the most insight into what a Viewer's experience will be... I'm running IE8 on my PC - and want to know what interactions my Viewers will be limited to... I'm finding most of the blogs are about publishing, contributing and management of SharePoint - but not about the Viewer who is using IE6:)

Comment: This is also one of the reasons that upgrading your enterprise to IE8 is recommended to be a part of your deployment of SharePoint 2010, but is often swept under the carpet due to "cost".

Comment: You're welcome, Amy. Glad it helped!

I completely agree, James. I've also had clients that are not able to upgrade IE because they have third-party applications that will break.  It is unfortunate for the clients, and shameful for a vendor to tie their solution to an outdated technology.