# SharePoint 2010 and IE 6

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ie6

According to the documentation SharePoint 2010 does not support IE 6.

What we are wondering is does it simply not work at all or are there just a few limitations?

We have a situation where the IE 6 users will:

- Navigate around the site
- User a user control to register data
- View data in SharePoint Lists

All other work can be done by admins with access to IE 8.

Could we use IE 6 in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a thread from where this has been asked before.  One of the links contains screen shots.  It is quite ugly trying to use SP2010 with IE6.

[What SP2010 features don't work for a Visitor using IE6](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6848/what-sp2010-features-dont-work-for-a-visitor-using-ie6)

Comment: The links above are consistent with my experience. There's really no elegant way around it, you need to either upgrade or use a thin-client approach (i.e. Citrix) where users can load up IE7 just for your SP2010 site.

Answer (score 2):

The only real possible use for IE6 with SP2010 is browsing Publishing sites, where the markup has been crafted to work properly with IE6. It's doubtful any of the interactive elements or fluent UI will work properly at all with IE6.